# GDAL/OGR (Ogr2ogr) python binding windows OCI driver

Tags: python, driver, gdal, ogr, ogr2ogr

I installed **GDAL-3.3.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl** on windows and I am trying ogr2ogr.py in python. For defaults drivers work perfectly, but in support drivers is not OCI driver (https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/oci.html#vector-oci).  When I installed OsGeo4W, I chose OCI, so it works in ogr2ogr.exe, but not in python ogr2ogr.py.
I installed too cx_Oracle, works alone (SELECT...), but not with ogr2ogr.

How to install this OCI driver for python ogr2ogr?

```
import cx_Oracle
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo_utils.samples import ogr2ogr   
   
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client('C:\\Users\\peter\\Downloads\\instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.11.0.0.0dbru\\instantclient_19_11')
ogr2ogr.main(["", "--formats"])
```

Write to console all "Built-in by default" formats (drivers) from https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html